# Adding value to an existing dict's keys

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7

```
cars = {'2012':'BMW', '2013':'Ford'}
new_cars = ['Fiat', 'Renault']
```

I'm trying to get:

```
cars = {'2012':['BMW', 'Fiat'], '2013':['Ford', 'Renault']}
```

Meaning an element at position `0` from `new_cars` is being added to `cars'` item at position `0` and so on.

I applied a solution I found somewhere but it's flawed:

```
for car in new_cars:
    for k,v in cars.iteritems():
        cars[k] = [cars[k], car]
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an item at position `0`, they are unordered

Comment: _"Meaning an element at position 0 from new_cars is being added to car's item at position 0 and so on."_ - `cars` has no _position 0_. It has a position `"2012"`, and a position `"2013"`.

Comment: And `{['2012':'BMW', 'Fiat'], ['2011':'Ford', 'Renault]}` is syntactically invalid. `{'2012': ['BMW', 'Fiat'], '2011': ['Ford', 'Renault]}` is correct

Comment: thanks for correction. I made up this by hand that's why was incorrect. Will fix that.

Comment: @Kyle don't change code, especially in questions where changing/fixing code might render the whole question pointless. If you spot typo leave comment telling the OP and let him fix it, if it was really a typo.

Comment: @ShadowWizard even when the typos are so clearly typos and easily correctable? I was careful not to alter the *logic* in any way, or to correct any syntax errors, etc.

Comment: @nutship, the errors in question can be seen by clicking on the "edited [x] minutes ago" link above Shadow Wizard's usercard. Specifically, `car's` should be `cars`'s (since you don't have a variable called `car`, and since the apostrophe isn't part of the code) and `2011` in the updated dictionary should be `2013` to match the original.

Comment: @Kyle better be careful than sorry, yes. (Just my opinion, others might agree with you, you won 3/2 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2010027))

Comment: @Shadow Okay, that's fair. I'll comment with suggested fixes next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have your value be a list.

example:

```
>>> cars = {}
>>> cars['2012'] = ['BMW', ' Fiat']
>>> cars['2013'] = ['Ford', 'Renault']
>>> cars
{'2013': ['Ford', 'Renault'], '2012': ['BMW', ' Fiat']}
>>> cars['2012'].append('Toyota')
>>> cars
{'2013': ['Ford', 'Renault'], '2012': ['BMW', ' Fiat', 'Toyota']}
>>> cars['2012']
['BMW', ' Fiat', 'Toyota']
```

A more robust example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# initiate the dict
cars = defaultdict(list)

# function for adding cars
def add_cars(year, new_cars):
    if isinstance(cars, (list, set)):
        # if more than 1 new_cars
        cars[year].extend(new_cars)
    else:
        cars[year].append(new_cars)

# add starting cars
add_cars('2012', 'BMW')
add_cars('2013', 'Ford')
# add new cars
add_cars('2012', 'Fiat')
add_cars('2013', 'Renault')
# view
print cars

>>> 
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'2013': ['Ford', 'Renault'], '2012': ['BMW', 'Fiat']})
```

There is also the option to do this with a dictionary:

```
>>> cars = {'2012':['BMW'], '2013':['Ford']}
>>> new_cars = {'2012':['Fiat'], '2013':['Renault']}
>>> for k, v in new_cars.iteritems():
    cars[k].extend(v)


>>> cars
{'2013': ['Ford', 'Renault'], '2012': ['BMW', 'Fiat']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the above. Perhaps I applied it wrongly (solution #1) because my code is adding every list element (not just the current one) to the dict key. Can you have a look please: `for k,v in cars.iteritems():
 for car in new_cars:
  cars[k].append(car)` which results in `{'2013': ['BMW', 'Fiat', 'Renault'], '2012': ['Ford', 'Fiat', 'Renault']}` p.s.For the time being I unaccepted your answer cuz maybe someone comes with solution for this comment.

Comment: Your problem is that you are adding each car in new_cars to each key in the dictionary. Your code is very ambiguous, you need to specify for each car, which key you want to add it to, you can not just assume the dictionary/code/python will know which key you want to add each car to. Hence the code I wrote where you specify the year for the car...

Comment: @nutship There is no loop in this answer. Your problem is that you don't yet understand that dicts are unordered. You simply cannot assume anything about the order in which a dict is enumerated. The documentation makes that clear.